# Implement filecounter with mvvm light

Tags: c#, mvvm, win-universal-app

Sorry for maybe dumb question, I've tried to find something on this topic, but had nothing in result.

So I got the UWP Windows store app using MVVM Light and SQLite.Net that adds some files in database. I'd like to keep track of number of files added to database, so I've created a class and static field for it:

```
public class Vars : ObservableObject
{
    public static Counter MyCounter = new Counter() { SongCounter = 0 };
}

public class Counter : ObservableObject
{
    private int songCounter;
    public int SongCounter
    {
        get { return songCounter; }
        set
        {
            songCounter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Dataservice` class that provides methods for the database connection I used `myCounter` to count the number of added files, like this:

```
public class Dataservice
{
    public static void RebuildLibrary()
    {
        //getting fileList
        foreach(var file in fileList)
        {
            //doing some stuff here
            Vars.MyCounter.SongCounter++
        }
    }
}
```

(Should also note that this part works - `MyCounter` is really increments)
And, finally there's the field in the `MainViewModel` called `CounterText` that is binded to XAML:

```
private string counterText;
public string CounterText
{
        get { return counterText; }
        set
        {
            counterText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
}
```

The dumb question is - how to bind `MyCounter` with `CounterText`? I've tried to set

```
CounterText = Vars.MyCounter.SongCounter.ToString();
```

in the `MainViewModel` constructor but it's not getting updated. Should I use Messenger to send `CounterText` some notifications? Or am I completely wrong and there is an easier way to achieve my goal? :)

Answer (score 0):

In my perspective,
Dont use a model for just a counter. Instead remove ++ in Foreach that will trigger PropertyChanged in each loop and use `Count` outside the loop.

```
CounterText  = filelist.Count;
```

CounterText should be changed to SongCount typeof `int` and use `IValueConverter` if needed.

Make sure your `RaisePropertyChanged();` is triggered correct, arent you supposed to do this???

```
 RaisePropertyChanged("CounterText");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use `fileList.Count()` because I'd like to show the progress. For instance, if I have 5000 objects to insert in database, I'd like to see how many files are actually added to understand how many there are left.  As for the `RaisePropertyChanged` of `CounterText` - it's just doesn't fire up with my old construction. I'll try to use yours and see what happen :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after struggling for a while I finally managed to solve the problem and decided to post an answer for those, who interest.
Actually, I came to the thought that the original mechanism was not working because there wasn't the binding. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that the `RaisePropertyChanged()` event affects only UI that is binded tj the property.
Anyway, I decided to use `Messenger` class provided by MVVM Light and get rid of `Counter` class. So in the `Dataservice` class there is:

```
public class Dataservice
{
    public static void RebuildLibrary()
    {
        string counter = "Files added: 0";
        int i;
        //getting fileList
        foreach (var file in fileList)
        {
            //doing some stuff here
            i++;
            counter = $"Files added: {i}";
            Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<string>(counter, "Counter"));
        }
    }
}
```

And in the MainViewModel constructor:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string counterText;
    public string CounterText
    {
        get {return counterText; }
        set
        {
            counterText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<string>>(this, (m) => CounterText = m.Content);
    }
}
```

Maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but at least it works. Anyway I'm still open for something different.